On page 31 of ISL, why is the minimum possible test MSE over all methods (dashed line) 1 instead of another number?
I am reading James, Witten, Hastie and Tibshirani's Introduction to Statistical Learning (2nd ed). On page 31, specifically Figure 2.9 in the right panel, I don't understand why the minimum possible test mean squared error (MSE) over all methods (dashed line) is 1 instead of another number. How is this number determined? Is there a rule of thumb, or is it arbitrarily chosen by the user?
Figure legends: Training MSE (grey curve), test MSE (red
curve), and minimum possible test MSE over all methods (dashed line). Squares
represent the training and test MSEs for the three fits shown in the left-hand
panel.


The text on p32 says
"The horizontal dashed line indicates Var($ϵ$),
the irreducible error in (2.3), which corresponds to the lowest achievable
test MSE among all possible methods."
So looking at the plot you show, they fairly explicitly indicate (albeit spread across two separate pieces of information) that the data were generated such that $\text{Var}(\epsilon)=1$.
This seems reasonably consistent with the noise around the black curve on the left hand side of Figure 2.9. Indeed the $ϵ_i$ values were probably just simulated as independent standard normals.
